# How to write td tag with baseurl link inside html?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter, html-table, echo

```
              <tbody>
                  <!-- Table contents-->
                  <?php
                     $i=1;
                     foreach($data as $row)
                     {
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td style='display:none;'>".$row->partner_id."</td>";
                        echo '<td><img src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/img/erplanka/profilepic.png" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail profimg"></td>';
                        echo "<td>".$row->cmp_name."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$row->name."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$row->mobile."</td>";
                        echo "<td style='display:none;'>".$row->email."</td>";
                        echo "<td style='display:none;'>".$row->address."</td>";
                        echo "<td style='display:none;'>".$row->country."</td>";
                        echo "<td style='display:none;'>".$row->province."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$row->district."</td>";
                        echo "<td>".$row->area."</td>";
                        echo '<td>
                              <div class="row row-icons text-center">
                                 <div class="col"><i class="fa fa-hand-o-up selectPartner" name="selectPartner" aria-hidden="true" value="'.$row->partner_id.'"></i></div>
                              </div>
                              </td>';
                        $i++;
                        }
                        ?>  
               </tbody>
```

I'm trying to add image to table row. But images are not appear while website running. In inspect element i saw baseurl is not working correctly. i think this is concatenation error. How to solve that problem?

Comment: I few comments on this code. You have a variable $i that is not being used. Also, in your views try to use the foreach endforeach instead of brackets.

Comment: Please do not use screenshots of your code or error messages and do not link to external sources. Screenshots are hard to read on mobile devices, they cannot be searched and none of us can copy, paste and run an image, links can get obsolete. Code should be included as text in the question itself. For more on this see 
[**Why may I not upload images of code**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) 
on SO when asking a question?

Comment: Please share more details - is this a problem of writing the markup properly, or of writing the proper markup? I'd assume this is **either** a PHP **or** an HTML problem, but not both

Answer (score 2):

Just like you're doing with the other variables, you can just break out of the string and insert your code:

```
echo '<td><img src="' . base_url() . 'assets/img/erplanka/profilepic.png" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail profimg"></td>';
```

I don't know if `base_url()` provides a '/' though, if not you should also add a '/' before 'assets'

Answer (score 0):

**you have to change that section as follow:**

```
<?php
    foreach($data as $row) {
      //........ other section of code
      $image = base_url() . 'assets/img/erplanka/profilepic.png';
      echo '<td><img src="' . $image. '"' . 'class="img-fluid img-thumbnail profimg"></td>';
    }
```

Comment: Why are you creating a variable just to concatenate in the next statement? Just use the base url inside the img src.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the line with the base_url() function is wrong.

```
echo '<td><img src="<?php echo base_url()?>assets/img/erplanka/profilepic.png" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail profimg"></td>';
```

should be

```
echo '<td><img src="' . base_url() . '/assets/img/erplanka/profilepic.png" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail profimg"></td>';
```